# Need a way to send response.body data from express (server.js) to React (client.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, express

I am working on a project where I provide a rest endpoint (POST) so that the backend can send the response body back to my react app. Then I should construct an HTML page and send that HTML back to the backend team. Now since my react app doesn't know when the backend will be sending the data, I initially get a blank page once I run it on my local as there is no data yet. Once I test that endpoint using postman by adding some content in the body and hitting send, my express (server.js) is able to get the data and I can console.log(data) it but I am unable to send it back to the react client.

Help is much appreciated!

server.js

```
server.post('/test', urlencodedParser, function(request, response) {
    request.accepts('application/json');
    const reqBody = request.body;
    console.log(reqBody); // I am able to get the data here.
```

app.js

```
export class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.props.actions.getInitialData(); // The actions.js has the end point information.
         console.log(this.props.initialData); // This is where I need to read the data for me to construct an HTML page which I can't
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className={Styles.container} data-test="appComponent">
                    <header>
                        <h1>(Demo Data)</h1>
                    </header>
                    <Page /> 
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    initialData: propTypes.object,
    actions: propTypes.object,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    initialData: state.initialData,
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(KspActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Here are the screenshots of express vs client browser.]

express js

[I see data in the console once I send the data using postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKerz.png)

browser

[I cant see any data on the client browser]

actions.js

```
export function getInitialData() {
    return function(dispatch) {
        const url = `${INTERNAL_ROUTES.KSP_URL}`; // this is '/test' route

        return axios.post(url)
            .then(response => {
                const respData = response.data;
                console.log(respData); // Not able to console.log the data on update from the backend
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
}
```

reducer.js

```
case types.GET_KSP_DATA: {
            return {
                ...state,
                kspData: [...state.kspData, action.data]
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to request the endpoint from the frontend application, receive it and display the data as you wish in your application.

So something like this:

```
// actions.js (or where-ever your actions are defined)
getInitialData() {
return fetch('http://path.to/endpoint', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: {}
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
}).then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    return dispatch({ type: 'INITIAL_DATA', data)
  })
}
```

Reducer:

```
const initialDataReducer = (initialState = {}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'INITIAL_DATA':
       return {
         ...state,
         ...action.data // NEVER use ... to spread return data, it gets messy and confusing. This is just an example.
       }
    }
}
```

assuming your reducer is connected to your app/component, you should be able to get your data in to the component. One thing to note is that `componentDidMount` will not have the data as you are calling the action there and `componentDidMount` only runs once. Instead, `componentDidUpdate` will receive the changes:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.initialData != prevProps.initialData) {
    console.log(this.props.initialData)
  }
}
```

Obviously there's some missing stuff / rough edges here but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: I tried it. But unfortunately no result yet. I have updated the react file to log the response body in componentDidUpdate method but still I am unable to receive the response from the post call. Basically the react app is unable to load the page dynamically whenever the data is posted from the backend.

Comment: I am using axios for requesting data by the way. I have updated my question by adding an image for clarity.

Comment: Can you add your action and reducer code? They’re pretty vital.

Comment: Thanks. When you the component mounts and the action `getInitialData` is run, does the function actually get called? I suggest either adding `console.log` or a breakpoint in the Chrome debugger (before the axios call. Maybe even get rid of it so you can verify the function actually works). I don't have much experience with Axios so if you're still struggling with that I suggest asking another question specifically about that. If you get `axios.post` working, you're gonna need to call `dispatch({ type: types.GET_KSP_DATA, data })` otherwise the reducer won't be initiated.

Comment: Yes. It runs the getInitialData and returns an empty object since no data has been returned yet from the backend. But when I send the response body using postman the react app should be updated and receive the data in the App Component